# Confusion regarding subset_fitter() functionality from CompleteMeasurementFitter() in Qiskit.Ignis

Tags: qiskit

I have been experimenting with the measurement mitigation module in Qiskit Ignis lately. I determined a calibration matrix $M$ with the help of `CompleteMeasurementFitter(..., qubit_list=qubit_list)` (calibration circuits and state labels given by `complete_meas_cal(..., qubit_list=qubit_list)`).

I have `qubit_list = [0, 1, 2]` and

```
state_labels = ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

If I remember correctly, Qiskit follows the convention that the rightmost character in the state label refers to the first qubit in the list, and so forth. 
I want to find the calibration matrix for the qubit subsystem `[1, 2]` with the `subset_fitter()` function. When I went through the source code, I struggled with the line where the reduced state labels are computed:

> ```
> state_labels_reduced = []
> for label in self.state_labels:
>     tmplabel = [label[l] for l in qubit_sublist_ind]
>     state_labels_reduced.append(''.join(tmplabel))
> ```

`qubit_sublist_ind` is a list of indices, which maps the reduced qubit list to the original one, in my case:

```
qubit_sublist_ind = [1, 2]
```

What confuses me now is that the quoted code snippet produces

```
state_labels_reduced = ['00', '01', '10', '11', '00', '01', '10', '11']
```

while I would expect

```
state_labels_reduced = ['00', '00', '01', '01', '10', '10', '11', '11']
```

since qubit 0 should refer to the rightmost character in each original state label. I would expect it to be simply stripped off. What is wrong here? Maybe I just confused myself. Thanks for your help!